# Subsetting NYC shapefile to Manhattan using Geopandas

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I have a shapefile of NYC which I would like to reduce to cover only Manhattan, using geopandas. (source: https://www1.nyc.gov/site/tlc/about/tlc-trip-record-data.page).

Thanks for any suggestions!!!

Already tried https://mygeodata.cloud/ but could not get it to work...

My overall goal is to later check if certain lat/lon points are within the shapefile of Manhattan, but currently, it would do that for NYC and thus include points that are actually outside Manhattan.

Comment: https://imgur.com/cyCC9bt

Comment: @Steven can you post that code as an answer?

Comment: @joris I would, but I'm not quite sure if this is what the poster wants since there's no example dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you're using the following shapefile:
[image]

Except for the geometry column in your `GeoDataFrame`, it acts just like a Pandas `DataFrame`. Thus, you can subset your `GeoDataFrame` like what you would do with Pandas.

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file('taxi_zones.shp')

# only keep Manhattan
gdf = gdf[gdf.borough == 'Manhattan']

# you can check it:
gdf.borough.value_counts()
```